# Memory Leaks Causes High Energy Impact For An iOS App?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

I developed an app that communicates with multiple devices by socket connection. Once the app is running it searches for the devices and connects with them. Each connection is ran in a thread. I checked the memory when the app is running, it rises about 20+ Mb. I don't know if this is really high for an app, but the energy impact is very high.

I tried using the tools to check whether I am using too much heap memory or I have a lot of leaks. Well, the result is I do have a lot of leaks, but does this lead to very high energy impact? or there could be other reasons?

In some iPhones, the phone will overheat after running my app for awhile. Especially iPhone 7.

Comment: No, there generally won't be much of a causal relationship between leaks and energy impact. So, when you solve your leaks (which you have to do anyway), don't expect that to necessarily solve the energy issues. It's theoretically possible that the two issues could be correlated (e.g. maybe you're orphaning threads that are spinning away, which could account for both memory and performance issues), but not necessarily so.

Comment: @Rob Alright. Thank you!